# What are the important specs for inductor in passive tone control?

Tags: inductor, passive-filter

I'm pretty much an electronics newbie. I'm working through some circuits in "Electronic Projects for Musicians". It has a "Passive Tone Control" which seemed like an easy start. Unsure if I can reproduce the circuit here (if that's allowed, I mean). But anyway it has a rotary switch that connects one of 5 capacitors (0.01uF to 0.22uF in range) to an inductor.

It lists the inductor as 5 or 6H center tapped. Then references a part (Mouser 42TM019) with primary impedance 10k ohm at 1Hz, secondary impedance 600 ohm. Primary resistance 600 ohm, secondary 100 ohm.

I've not been able to find that part in stock. Mouser has some others, but I don't know what specs are important to keep and what are not. For example 42TL021-RC where secondary impedance is 600 ohm but primary is 4k ohm instead of 10k.

Could someone explain what might be the important bits of an inductor in this case?

Comment: Unless it's a passive crossover, usually inductors are made by negative feedback with capacitors as the signal currents are low.

Comment: Check these schematics and see how many magnetics you can spot   https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf4/84/8320/831904-onkyo/htr960.pdf?cb4430fb7b54dc82d305806960360955&take=binary  then be more application specific

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You are describing an audio transformer, not an inductor. An inductor has only one winding, though it can have taps. High performance audio transformers can be a bit expensive, and have a bottom limit of 40HZ. Used mainly for both galvanic isolation and impedance matching.

Comment: Sparky256 is correct about the difference between an inductor and a transformer. However, in your circuit are both primary and secondary of the transformer used, or is one  left open circuited (unconnected)? You can use either  the primary or secondary of a transformer as an inductor as long as you leave the opposite winding open circuited. Perhaps that's the case here. Best to include a schematic with your question. A picture is worth a thousand words, they say.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The book lists it as an inductor. I'll read about the differences.

I believe the secondary is left open. One side of it has notes on the schematic "NC" where NC means not connected. 

Here's a schematic of it I found through google image search: https://img.scoop.it/d-fGlqR1eDmYakqsWaigcTl72eJkfbmt4t8yenImKBVvK0kTmF0xjctABnaLJIm9

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 That opened a home theater schematic document. I'm not sure of the relevance.

Comment: Baxendall passive tone controls use no inductors because inductor of value in Henries add distortion, from remanence. That’s why you should not use them.